# How to Remove Keys from SourceTree SSH Agent

Tags: windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree, ssh-agent

I am using SourceTree on Windows.  I have SSH keys to validate the server connection.  So, when I start Sourcetree it launches the SSH Agent which then asks me for the passwords for each key. That is fine.

However, while I can see an option in SourceTree to "Add SSH Key" I cannot see how to remove one.  My actual problem is that, due to a misleading error message, I re-added the key and it now has the same key multiple times and asks for too many passwords at start-up!  But, more generally, i would like to be able to list and remove keys from the SSH agent.

I have tried using command line `ssh-add` but it says

> Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory

(Tried this both with windows CMD shell and in the Git bash terminal that SourceTree launches)

I see a running `ssh-agent.exe` process in Task Manager when SourceTree is running - in the Details tab.  But in the Services tab it says the service is stopped.  So, I guess SourceTree has started it but how do I connect to it?  Alternatively, how to tell SourceTree  not to start it's own but use the Windows Service?

I am using the OpenSSH SSH client (in SourceTree options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found my own answer.  There doesn't appear to be a way to connect to the agent directly, but the keys are stored directly in the SourceTree config.  `Tools | Options | General | SSH Client Configuration : SSH Key`.  This field is a semi-colon separated list of paths to the keys to load.  I just removed the duplicates from there.

Now have issues getting SourceTree and OpenSSH Agent to co-exist, but that's a different question.  At least it only asks me for each password once.